# Send Push Notification using Spring Boot for Calendar on particular time

Tags: spring-boot, websocket, push-notification, scheduled-tasks, alert

I want to Send Push Notification using Spring Boot for Calendar on the particular time.

The person will get alert/notification for Task at particular Time based on Calendar alert they have set.

Can you please me tell me what will be required? Kafka, Firebase FCM, WebSocket or any other alternative -  which may be more effective?

Comment: Before anyone can answer you need to provide more information. Do you mean sending to a mobile App or a browser?

Comment: Client app from a Browser

Answer (score 0):

You Can Explore Cron Job or Scheduler to perform this job you must have value at backend for specific alarms , further more you can use java runnable Interface to create threads.